# Web Service Deployment

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment, package

Hi
Does any body know how to pakage several webservices into one before deployment using ASP.Net.
Like say for instance, I have 5 web services and i need to deploy all of them in such a way that the user need to click jus one link.
Does anybody know how to do that?...

Answer (score 0):

What version of .NET? Web deploy can do this.